# How to solve unhashable type:numpy ndarray

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I apply a regular knn method to my algorithm, I come across this problem:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

```
def classify(inx, dataset, labels, k):

    dist = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(inx - dataset), axis=1))

    k_labels = [labels[index] for index in np.argsort(dist)[0 : k]]

    lab = collections.Counter(k_labels).most_common(1)[0][0]
    return lab
```

The error:

```
 File "C:/Users/xjy/untitled0.py", line 166, in classify
    lab = collections.Counter(k_labels).most_common(1)[0][0]

  File "C:\Users\xjy\Anaconda3\envs\xjy\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 535, in __init__
    self.update(*args, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\xjy\Anaconda3\envs\xjy\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 622, in update
    _count_elements(self, iterable)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Comment: can someone point my mistake and solve this ?

Comment: can give the output snippet of print (k_labels)

Comment: yes,the print of it is:[array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your k_labels is `[array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)]` then

Use

```
lab = collections.Counter(k_labels[0]).most_common(1)[0][0]
```